# Ubuntu Nvidia Twinview error / Flash lag

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, twinview

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with '2' Nvidia GTS-250 GPU's. I am trying to get TwinView to work. Currently I have everything working as far as both screens are on and I can drag between them and use workspace switcher fine. I am having a few different issues, my assumptions lead me to believe all of them are related to the TwinView display. The issues I am having are as follows:

-Once logged in an error is displayed stating: "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors. none of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes: Trying modes for CRTC 351 CRTC 351: trying mode 3840x1200@50Hz with output at 1920x1080@50Hz (pass 0) CRTC 351: trying mode 3840x1200@50Hz with output at 1920x1080@50Hz (pass 1)

- At this point all system and application windows & font are really large including the desktop text. All I do is close out of this error. And the font and window size issues are gone. Seems like the display quickly refreshes when I close out of this error.(Not sure what happens that quick fixes the issue, until I need to logout and back in of course.)
- Any videos streamed through any browser do not work fully. It lags and chops up a bit. Not sure if this is a flash issue or not. I currently have flashplugin-installer 11.1.102.63 installed from the software center. I have read about an issue with the current version of flash and "Gnash" causing issues. Double checked, I do not have Gnash installed.

I'm gonna try and think ahead here of any possible file or setting anyone would need to see to help with this issue: I posted my current xorg.conf file and results of xrandr command here:

http://pastebin.com/ZtY74XG6

My setup consits of the 2 Nvidia GTS-250 GPU's. Both monitors are connected to the same(first) GPU card. The monitors in use are an LG-47 LED and a Samsung-24 LCD. Just a standard left(default-LG)display --> right(secondary-Samsung)display

The Nvidia driver I have installed is from the Additonal drivers panel, The Nvidia accelerated graphics driver(version current)[Recommended]. The other option listed is the (post-release updates)(version current-updates).

I have a fully updated OS with nothing out of the ordinary software running. I never had these issues before I setup Twinview but I do vaguely remember having to uninstall and reinstall flash around when I setup TwinView also.

Just to provide some more detail: If I attempt to go into displays, It only detects 1 large unknown monitor with a resolution of 3840x1200 and wont allow for any changes(I Since I have the Nvidia drivers I utilise the nvidia x-server settings. The X server settings GUI shows the following(relevant info):

```
Operating System: Linux-x86_64 Nvidia 
Driver Version: 295.20
```

XServer Display Config: (GUI) Shows the LG and Samsung monitors in the correct positions.

```
Configuration: TwinView
Resolution: Auto
Position: Absolute (only difference is the samsung display position is: +1920+0)
Panning: LG-1920x1080 Samsung-1920x1200
```

I hope I have explained this well enough in detail. I'm honestly not worried about the display issues and error message once logging in. Easy enough to just close it out and act like it doesn't happen(unless you believe they are somehow related). The only reason I included all the details with that is I do believe the issues are related in some way. For the past 2 days I have researched issues online and found a ton of workarounds for Twinview to work display properly(assuming this is causing the flash video issues.) I have followed a few different tutorials for Twinview and Nvidia drivers all of which didn't correct the issue or left me unable to boot(Had to boot to recovery console and restore old versions of files I modified during the various tuts to allow boot to desktop) (Good thing I backed them all up 1st :))

My main concern is to allow videos to stream and play properly without lag and screen chop/flickering. But since I already uninstalled and reinstalled the same version of flash I fear it may be related to the display error.

Thanks for all the help. Let me know if you need me to provide any more info, I'm not moving until it works so I'll be here all night =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can at least help you with your first problem.

**Background:**

The message you have to click away after login comes from the "xrandr" plugin, because it tries to automatically detect your monitors. Since your xorg.conf says you have a screen with a resolution of 3840x1200 (TwinView) and xrandr doesn't find a corresponding monitor to display this, it throws up this message. So even if it's almost impossible to find the solution in the internet (maybe I just had luck with my search terms at google ;-) ) it's as simples as could be.

**Solution:**

1. install dconf editor --> sudo apt-get install dconf*
2. start dconf-editor
3. go to /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr
4. uncheck "Active"
5. restart your XServer (Ctrl+Alt+Backspace)
6. smile how easy this was ;-)

For your second problem it may be your running xinerama ?!? Did you try a game that needs 3D-Acceleration (i.e. openarena), it's the best way to verify that your nvidia drivers are installed correctly and working with TwinView (because there's no acceleration with xinerama).
I'm not sure about that for now; I've to verify your xorg.conf with mine at home - because I don't have everything about that completly in mind.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't dconf part of Gnome3? And also, doesn't 11.10(!) does not have Gnome3?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, because I use Mint 12. I had to install dconf separately. But the first step won't hurt eather; it'll just tell you there's nothing to install.

Comment: Your solution corrected my issue, Thank you very much! :)